# How can I prevent Blender from making a dump when crashing

Tags: system

Blender recently caused a severe problem with my operating system (OpenSuse 15.2) when it crashed, leaving a huge data dump, which caused my whole system to freeze or crash thereafter, whenever it was put under any stress - even if Blender was not opened.

It was also extremely difficult to rectify the problem as the system would usually freeze when I tried to open Blender, or if I managed to open it, if I tried close Blender, even without saving. Eventually, I managed to clear the problem by logging in as Root, opening Blender, then saving the .blend file that was open when it crashed.

Is there a setting to prevent Blender from making these huge data dumps when crashing?

Comment: If you start blender with `blender --help` among the options are `--disable-crash-handler` and `--disable-abort-handler` would assume the former will do it.

Comment: Thanks @batFINGER - I'll check it out.